# How to draw a histogram inside a frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

So far I'm running `plt.hist` function and saving the result in an image and then plotting  using the following code inside a `mdiArea`

```
def test(self):
    self.result = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow()
    self.result.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("subWindow"))
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('Result.png'))
    graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.result)
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.result)
    graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, pixmap.width() + 10, pixmap.height() + 10))
    graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicView"))
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
    scene.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(pixmap.rect()))
    scene.update()
    graphicsView.setScene(scene)
    self.result.resize(pixmap.width() + 60, pixmap.height() + 60)
    self.result.setWindowTitle('Results')
    self.result.show()
```

But when I plot a big data set the histogram gets too small. Is there some way to plot using `plt.hist` directly inside de `mdiArea`

I have this:
[image]

And I want this inside the window:

[image]

By the way, is there a better way to show this data inside the histogram?

Comment: The code is a little extensive but what really matters is that part. I have a mdiArea and I want to plot a histogram

Comment: if it makes sense for your case maybe consider removing outliers and change y axis range to maybe 0 to 0.05 for the chart you are showing.

Comment: @asdas 1) Explain yourself better, I don't understand your question. 2) I have not asked for your project code but an MRE, if you do not know what it is then read the previous link. 3) In the code you provide there is nothing about matplotlib

Comment: @asdas What I understand is that you currently save the plot in "Result.png" and then load it as the QGraphicsView that is in the mdiarea but instead you want to show the plot directly in mdiarea, am I correct? If so, then I will post an answer without taking into account the code you provide

Comment: Exactly. My code is just to show what I've done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a canvas using the FigureCanvas of the Qt4 backend<sup>(1)</sup>, in the following code I show an example:

```py
import numpy as np

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
    FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,
)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiArea)

        mu, sigma = 100, 15
        x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

        self._canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        self._ax = self._canvas.figure.subplots()
        n, bins, patches = self._ax.hist(
            x, 50, density=1, facecolor="green", alpha=0.75
        )
        self._ax.set_xlabel("Smarts")
        self._ax.set_ylabel("Probability")
        self._ax.set_title(r"$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=100,\ \sigma=15$")
        self._ax.axis([40, 160, 0, 0.03])
        self._ax.grid(True)

        widget = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        widget.setCentralWidget(self._canvas)
        widget.addToolBar(
            QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self._canvas, self)
        )
        sub_window = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow()
        sub_window.setWidget(widget)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(sub_window)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

[image]

---

<sup>(1) [Embedding in Qt](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html)</sup>